# Error calculating a list of numbers in a certain order - a JavaScript engine error or a JavaScript language error?

Tags: javascript

The following code generates a strange error when taking the values from the fields and calculate the sum of them. We the following scenarios:

1. If you are using the numbers from the field, the sum result will be "-3.552713678800501e-15".
2. If you are changing the sign from the bigger number to the smaller ones (both of them), you're going to have the same result/error.
3. a) Fill the first field with 36.80, the second with -64.50, and the third with 27.70
   or
   b) Fill the first field with -36.80, the second with 64.50, and the third with -27.70

- you will have the same error.

```js
var initMaskMoney = function() {
  $(".priceinput").maskMoney({
    thousands: '',
    decimal: ',',
    precision: 2,
    allowZero: true,
    allowNegative: true
  });
}

var checkPayForm = function() {
  var invSums = function() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('totValue');
    var invTotSum = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
      var curIsSel = $(arr[i]).closest("td").next("td").find("input[class=chkInv]");

      if ($(curIsSel).is(":checked")) {
        var curSum = $(arr[i]);
        var curSumVal = $(curSum).val().replace(',', '.');
        var invSum = $(arr[i]).closest("td").next("td").find("input[class=invvalue]");

        invTotSum += parseFloat(curSumVal);
      }
    }

    return invTotSum;
  };

  $(".chkInv").on("click", function() {
    var totSum = invSums();
    if (totSum == 0) {
      $(".totalbuc").html("<strong>Remaining amount: <span class=\"btn btn-success\">" + totSum.toFixed(2) + "</span></strong>");
    } else {
      $(".totalbuc").html("<strong>Remaining amount: <span class=\"btn btn-danger\">" + totSum.toFixed(2) + "</span></strong>");
    }

    console.log("totSum: " + totSum);
  });
}

initMaskMoney();
checkPayForm();
```

```css
.padL20 { padding-left: 20px; }
.padT10 { padding-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding:30px;">
  <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-body">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12 text-center">
        <div class="totalbuc"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="dvdocstosubstract" style="display: block;">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">List of docs to substract from</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>CF 52806 / 22.02.2021</td>
                <td class="padL20"><input id="TotalPriceD" name="[0][TotalPriceD]" type="text" class="form-control input-small priceinput totValue" value="-64,50"></td>
                <td class="padL20"><input type="checkbox" id="InvIDChkD" name="[0][InvIDChkD][]" class="chkInv"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group padT10" id="dvdocs">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">List of docs to substract from</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <td>CF 56960 / 15.04.2021</td>
                <td class="padL20"><input id="TotalPrice" name="[0][TotalPrice]" type="text" class="form-control input-small priceinput totValue" value="36,80"></td>
                <td class="padL20"><input type="checkbox" id="InvIDChk" name="[0][InvIDChk][]" class="chkInv"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="padT10">CF 57187 / 19.04.2021</td>
                <td class="padL20 padT10"><input id="TotalPrice" name="[1][TotalPrice]" type="text" class="form-control input-small priceinput totValue" value="27,70"></td>
                <td class="padL20 padT10"><input type="checkbox" id="InvIDChk" name="[1][InvIDChk][]" class="chkInv"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No matter what function I've used to calculate the sum of these numbers, the result is the same.

What do you think - did I find an error in JavaScript engine?

Comment: "did I find an error in JavaScript engine" - to find that out, try to isolate the problem and post some 5 lines of code that reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with how floats are represented by computers, they aren't exact, just an approximation. You could try opening your browser's console and running `.1+.1+.1` which will equal `0.30000000000000004`. These errors are usually small enough that you could simply resolve your issue by returning `Number(invTotSum).toFixed(2)`

That said, these errors add up with each sum and it is strongly discouraged to use floats for currency arithmetic. Best practice is to convert to the smallest unit (cents), do your math then convert it back to dollars